Scala 3 macro: creating a path-dependent method signature
In Scala 3, I'm trying to generate a method within a macro that has a path-dependent type, but I can't find an API that lets me create such a signature.
Given the following definition:
trait Foo:
  type Out

I want to generate a def of the following shape:
def bar(x: Foo): x.Out

So I use Symbol.newMethod like so:
Symbol.newMethod(
  Symbol.spliceOwner,
  "bar",
  MethodType(List("x"))(_ => List(TypeRepr.of[Foo]), mt => ???))

But how do I specify the ????
I need to reference x there somehow, but there doesn't seem to be an API for that.
Looking at the generated Tree for such code, I see the following:
TypeSelect(Ident("x"), "Out"))

But Ident requires a TermRef, is there a way to acquire one for the method's argument?
Thanks
